# Zebra puzzle - who lives on which floor?

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I have a zebra/Einstein type Prolog puzzle very similar to the one depicted here:

[A "Building" Riddle in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652482/a-building-riddle-in-prolog).

The riddle is:

> There are two buildings, each one has tree apartments (one apartment on each floor): one apartment of 3 rooms, one of 4 rooms and one of 5 rooms.
>
> Dana, Joni and Noah live in building 1. Ron, Gale and Aron live in building 2.
>
> Joni's apartment is higher then Dana's and Noah's. It means he lives on the third floor of building 1. Noah and Gale live on the same floor (in different buildings). Ron has one more room than Aron. Ron lives one floor above Gale. The highest apartment in building 2 is the 5 rooms apartment.

I need to find in which floor everyone lives.

This is the code.

```
solve([dana,building1,F1,R1],
      [noah,building1,F2,R2],
      [joni,building1,F3,R3],
      [gale,building2,F4,R4],
      [ron, building2,F5,R5],
      [aron,building2,F6,R6]) :-
   assign([1,2,3],[F1,F2,F3]),
   assign([1,2,3],[F4,F5,F6]),
   assign([3,4,5],[R1,R2,R3]),
   assign([3,4,5],[R4,R5,R6]),
   F3 > F2,
   F3 > F1,
   F2 =:= F4,
   R5 =:= R6-1,
   F5 =:= F4+1,
   (  F4 =:= 3, R4 =:= 5
   ;  F5 =:= 3, R5 =:= 5
   ;  F6 =:= 3, R6 =:= 5
   ).

assign(_,[]).
assign(Digs,[D|Vars]):-
   del(D,Digs,Digs1),
   assign(Digs1,Vars).

del(X,L,L1) :-
   remove(X,L,L1).

remove([],X,[]) :- !. 
remove([X|T],X,L1) :- !, remove(T,X,L1).   
remove([H|T],X,[H|L1]) :- remove(T,X,L1).
```

I don't understand which query to use with this following solution? When I try the query from the original post,

```
solve([dana,building1,F1,R1],[noah,building1,F2,R2],[joni,building1,F3,R3],
      [gale,building2,F4,R4],[ron, building2,F5,R5],[aron,building2,F6,R6]).
```

it says

```
Type error: `evaluable' expected, found `[]' (an empty_list)
In:
   [2] []>[]
   [1] solve([dana,building1|...],[noah,building1|...],[joni,building1|...],
             [gale,building2|...],[ron, building2|...],[aron,building2|...]) 
at  line 1
```

What is the correct query for this?

Thanks.

Comment: `solve` calls `assign`, which calls `del` which calls `remove`, which is not defined in this code. You&#39;re correct to call `solve`. You&#39;ll need to hunt for a definition of `remove`, likely somewhere around where you got this code from. Or it it&#39;s expecting it to be a built-in and you're running a different version of Prolog from the author.

Comment: [SWI's select/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select/3) is a natural fit to this problem.

Comment: @PaulBrown I've added remove but now it fails for another reason. can you possibly help? thanks.

Comment: BTW if you have a working code now, you can post it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and ask for it to be reviewed there, to get some feedback on the code, whether it can be coded differently / "better" / simpler, etc.  (hint: it can). Be sure to check that site's guidelines for asking if you decide to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is correct for the given code.

The code contains an error.

```
del(X,L,L1) :-
   remove(X,L,L1).   % WRONG
```

You need to change the order of arguments in the call to `remove/3`, to correspond to their use in the definition of `remove/3`.

You could discover it by testing *in the small*. Just trying the query `assign([1,2,3],Floors)` at the prompt, you'd discover whether it works *as intended* or not.

Or `del(D,[1,2,3],Digs1)`, following the `assign/2` definition,

```
assign([1,2,3],[D|Vars]):-
   del(D,[1,2,3],Digs1),
   ..... .
```

Or `remove(D,[1,2,3],Digs1)`, following the `del/3` definition,

```
del(D,[1,2,3],Digs1) :-
   remove(D,[1,2,3],Digs1).
```

Looking at the definition

```
remove([],   X,[]    ) :- !. 
remove([X|T],X,L1    ) :- !, remove(T,X,L1).
remove([H|T],X,[H|L1]) :- remove(T,X,L1).
```

knowing that our intended meaning for **`D`** is to hold one *digit* from among `[1,2,3]`,

*(the rest is intentionally left blank)*